# How do I make a reservation for shipping a bicyle with Turkish Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, bicycles, fragile-luggage

I will soon be travelling from Venice (Italy) to Seoul (South Korea). I plan to bring a bicycle with me. My first option is to travel via Turkish Airlines, which [carries bikes](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/sports-equipment/bicycle/) with reservation required. How can I make such a reservation? And should the weight of the bike be included in the baggage budget I have? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting Turkish Airlines?

Comment: I did (after posting my question, ops) and they replied to my call and to my message on Facebook. Apparently you need to a) buy a ticket, b) let them know your plans, c) arrive in the airport with a bike and pay 90 euros. Easy.

Comment: @albus_c That sounds like an answer.  And answering your own question *is* a thing

Comment: Alway the question if the bike is worth the effort

Answer (score 1):

from [OP in comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169630/how-do-i-make-a-reservation-for-shipping-a-bicyle-with-turkish-airlines/171264#comment423772_169630):

> they replied to my call and to my message on Facebook. Apparently you
> need to a) buy a ticket, b) let them know your plans, c) arrive in the
> airport with a bike and pay 90 euros. Easy